# Hausdorff dimension of Cantor set times interval?

Tags: measure-theory, cantor-set

What is the Hausdorff dimension of the set $C \times I \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $C$ is the standard Cantor set and $I$ is the unit interval? I know $dim_H (C) = \frac{ln2}{ln3}$ and I feel like there should be some easy argument here, but I'm not seeing one.

Comment: Do you know Fubini theorem for measures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual argument for the cantor set uses self symmetry. The (middle thirds) Cantor set is constructed by cutting the unit interval into thirds, removing the middle section, repeating the construction to the remaining intervals and continuing the process. The set of points which are not removed in this process are precisely the points of $C$

In the first step of the process above (removing the middle third of the unit interval) you have two intervals remaining. These intervals naturally partition $C$ into a disjoint union $C_0\cup C_1=C$, where $C_0$ is the set of points remaining after continuing the process on the interval $[0,1/3]$ and $C^1$ is the same for $[2/3,1]$. If you consider the (Hausdorff) volume of these sets, notice that $V(C_0)=V(C_1)$, since $C_0$ is a copy of $C_1$. By the partition we described above, we therefore ought to have
$$V(C)=V(C_0)+V(C_1)=2V(C_0)\;.$$
If you scale $C_0$ by a factor of 3, then by self similarity, you see you get $C$ again. In a $d$-dimensional space, volume scales as $\lambda^d$, where $\lambda$ is the scaling factor. For the Cantor set, that gives you
$$V(C)=3^dV(C_0)\;.$$
Combining that with the above equation gives
$$2V(C_0)=3^dV(C_0)\Rightarrow 2=3^d\;.$$
You solve that for the dimension and you get $d=\log(2)/\log(3)$.

Now, let's do the same trick for $I\times C$. Everything works the same, but when you scale by a factor of 3, you no longer get $C\times I$, you get $(C\times 3I)$. So then,
$$3*2V(C_0\times I)=3^dV(C_0\times I)\Rightarrow 1+\log(2)/\log(3)=d\;,$$
which is what you expect.

Comment: Your answer made me realize i have an additional question: what if we wanted to apply this reasoning to a situation where we have the real line instead of the interval? It seems like that would lead to the conclusion that the dimension would be $\frac{log(2)}{log(3)}$ which can't be the case.

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Not quite. The problem there is in the volume. The Hausdorff Volume of $\mathbb{R}\times C_0$ will not be finite so you can't naively cancel out the volumes.

Comment: Yeah I just realized that. So what argument do we use to claim that the volume is finite in our case?

Comment: @TheMountainThatCodes Any measure satisfies the property that $V(C)\leq V(E)$ if $C\subset E$ and both sets are measurable. Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: I mean i suspect that we have to take some kind of superset, but I'm not sure what set can we say has a finite s-Hausdorff measure for some arbitrary unknown s.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a special case of the following statement.

> let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. We have $$\dim(E \times I) = \dim(E) + 1$$

See either [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/189270/hausdorff-dimension-of-r-x-x), or Theorem 5.1 and Theorem 5.8 in Falconer's *The Geometry of Fractal Sets*.